# Export map as image by Openlayers

Tags: openlayers-2, geoserver

I am using `Openlayers` to publish maps and `Geoserver` as map server. Now I can add more than one layer in `Openlayers` like `WMS` , `Vector` , `WFS` and `Google Maps` as base map. How can i export map's current viewport as image.

**EDIT**: I need to print base layers also. Base layer may be Google maps , Bing maps etc.

Comment: Check out this Q/A, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21691919/export-map-in-openlayers

Comment: I tried this link earlier but it is not clear to me as Ralph Dell answered me.

Answer (score 1):

http://trac.osgeo.org/openlayers/wiki/TileStitchingPrinting

This has worked very well for me. Right now I am using OL2.12. If I remember correctly I had to tweak the OL control a little bit for my purposes. On the server side I am using python and as the directions say you need to install the PIL library. I have my python server side code sitting in my /cgi/print_image.cgi. It was not difficult to get set up.

Comment: I have never tried to print a google layer.